# How to create a product slider using a lists <li>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to achieve a product slider using the existing code below. The existing code uses lists to display all the products

[I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7CYS.png)

When the 5th product has been added, this is what it is displayed.

[The image when 5th products is added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkQBD.png)

I also tried the owl carousel product but this is what I get.

[Owl carousel plugin applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9LQG.png)

```
<div class="box-carousel">
                        <div class="bnr-carousel-item">
                           <div class="ec-shelfRole">
                              <ul class="ec-shelfGrid">
                                 <li class="ec-shelfGrid__item">
                                    <a href="/moc/guest/item">
                                       <img src="https://demo4.ec-cube.net/html/upload/save_image/0903163326_5b8ce3c697fad.jpg"/>
                                       <p class="ec-shelfGrid__title">さくさく♪クッキーアイス
                                       </p>
                                       <p class="ec-shelfGrid__plice">¥ 1,620
                                       </p>
                                       <ul class="ec-productRole ec-productRole__tags">
                                          <li class="ec-productRole__tag tag_1">新商品</li>
                                          <li class="ec-productRole__tag tag_2">おすすめ商品</li>
                                          <li class="ec-productRole__tag tag_3">限定商品</li>
                                       </ul>
                                    </a>
                                    <form>
                                       <div class="ec-productRole__actions">
                                          <div class="ec-select">
                                             <select>
                                                <option value="0">選択してください</option>
                                                <option value="1">チョコミント</option>
                                                <option value="2">ストロベリー</option>
                                                <option value="3">バニラ</option>
                                             </select>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="ec-numberInput"><span>数量</span>
                                             <input class="quantity form-control" type="number" name="quantity" value="1"/>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="ec-productRole__btn">
                                             <button class="ec-blockBtn--action add-cart">カートに入れる</button>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </form>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="ec-shelfGrid__item">
                                    <a href="/moc/guest/item">
                                       <img src="https://demo4.ec-cube.net/html/upload/save_image/0903163326_5b8ce3c697fad.jpg"/>
                                       <p class="ec-shelfGrid__title">さくさく♪クッキーアイス
                                       </p>
                                       <p class="ec-shelfGrid__plice">¥ 1,620
                                       </p>
                                       <ul class="ec-productRole ec-productRole__tags">
                                          <li class="ec-productRole__tag tag_1">新商品</li>
                                          <li class="ec-productRole__tag tag_2">おすすめ商品</li>
                                          <li class="ec-productRole__tag tag_3">限定商品</li>
                                       </ul>
                                    </a>
                                    <form>
                                       <div class="ec-productRole__actions">
                                          <div class="ec-select">
                                             <select>
                                                <option value="0">選択してください</option>
                                                <option value="1">チョコミント</option>
                                                <option value="2">ストロベリー</option>
                                                <option value="3">バニラ</option>
                                             </select>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="ec-numberInput"><span>数量</span>
                                             <input class="quantity form-control" type="number" name="quantity" value="1"/>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="ec-productRole__btn">
                                             <button class="ec-blockBtn--action add-cart">カートに入れる</button>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </form>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="ec-shelfGrid__item">
                                    <a href="/moc/guest/item">
                                       <img src="https://demo4.ec-cube.net/html/upload/save_image/0903163326_5b8ce3c697fad.jpg"/>
                                       <p class="ec-shelfGrid__title">さくさく♪クッキーアイス
                                       </p>
                                       <p class="ec-shelfGrid__plice">¥ 1,620
                                       </p>
                                       <ul class="ec-productRole ec-productRole__tags">
                                          <li class="ec-productRole__tag tag_1">新商品</li>
                                          <li class="ec-productRole__tag tag_2">おすすめ商品</li>
                                          <li class="ec-productRole__tag tag_3">限定商品</li>
                                       </ul>
                                    </a>
                                    <form>
                                       <div class="ec-productRole__actions">
                                          <div class="ec-select">
                                             <select>
                                                <option value="0">選択してください</option>
                                                <option value="1">チョコミント</option>
                                                <option value="2">ストロベリー</option>
                                                <option value="3">バニラ</option>
                                             </select>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="ec-numberInput"><span>数量</span>
                                             <input class="quantity form-control" type="number" name="quantity" value="1"/>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="ec-productRole__btn">
                                             <button class="ec-blockBtn--action add-cart">カートに入れる</button>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </form>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="ec-shelfGrid__item">
                                    <a href="/moc/guest/item">
                                       <img src="https://demo4.ec-cube.net/html/upload/save_image/0903163326_5b8ce3c697fad.jpg"/>
                                       <p class="ec-shelfGrid__title">さくさく♪クッキーアイス
                                       </p>
                                       <p class="ec-shelfGrid__plice">¥ 1,620
                                       </p>
                                       <ul class="ec-productRole ec-productRole__tags">
                                          <li class="ec-productRole__tag tag_1">新商品</li>
                                          <li class="ec-productRole__tag tag_2">おすすめ商品</li>
                                          <li class="ec-productRole__tag tag_3">限定商品</li>
                                       </ul>
                                    </a>
                                    <form>
                                       <div class="ec-productRole__actions">
                                          <div class="ec-select">
                                             <select>
                                                <option value="0">選択してください</option>
                                                <option value="1">チョコミント</option>
                                                <option value="2">ストロベリー</option>
                                                <option value="3">バニラ</option>
                                             </select>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="ec-numberInput"><span>数量</span>
                                             <input class="quantity form-control" type="number" name="quantity" value="1"/>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="ec-productRole__btn">
                                             <button class="ec-blockBtn--action add-cart">カートに入れる</button>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </form>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/carousel-item-->
                     </div>
```

Comment: do you agree to use `js`,or only `css`,(if `css` then not possible)

Comment: Also,Do you wan't infinity scroll or endup once product is over

Comment: I want to end up once product is over.

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu its already working now. I set the loop on the javascript to false

<script>
   $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
       loop:false,
       margin:10,
       nav:true,
       responsive:{
           0:{
               items:1
           },
           600:{
               items:3
           },
           1000:{
               items:4
           }
       }
   })
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the owl-carousel and I only deleted the ul and li and it's class

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkXxa.png)